# Plotting random point on Function - Pandas

Tags: python, function, pandas, plot, ipython

I want to graph a function 2D or 3D
for example a f(x) = sin(x)

Then randomly plot a certain amount of points

I am using IPython and I think this might be possible using Pandas

Comment: Why `pandas`? You can use `numpy.random`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.random.uniform` to generate a few random points along x-axis and calculate corresponding f(x) values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate 20 points from uniform (-3,3)
x = np.random.uniform(-3, 3, size=20)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, any insight on how I can delay the plotting so I can see the point appearing in sequence?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Pandas...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=linspace(0,8)
y=sin(x)
DF=pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y})
```

plot values:

```
DF.plot(x='x',y='y')
```

make a random index:

```
RandIndex=randint(0,len(DF),size=20)
```

use it to select from original DF and plot:

```
DF.iloc[RandIndex].plot(x='x',y='y',kind='scatter',s=120,ax=plt.gca())
```

[image: Sin wave and random points]

Answer (score 0):

You should post example code so people can demonstrate it more easily.

```
(numpy.random.random(10)*x_scale)**2
```

Generate an array of random numbers between 0 and 1, scale as appropriate (so for (-10,0);

```
10*numpy.random.random(100) -10
```

then pass this to any function that can calculate the value of f(x) for each element of the array. 
Use shape() if you need to play around with layout of the array.